# Finding the number of all segments of length at least $k$ in an array of length $n$

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find the number of all segments of length at least $k$ in an array of length $n$.

My solution is
$$\frac{n(n - 1)}{2} - \frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{2}$$
i.e., I subtract the number of length smaller segments than $k$ from the total number.

But the answer was
$$\frac{(n- k + 1)(n - k + 2)}{2}$$
Can you explain my mistake?

---

Example:

$k = 2$ and $n = 6$

$1$ $2$ $3$ $4$ $5$ $6$

answers:

${1 2};$ ${2 3};$ ${3 4};$ ${4 5};$ ${5 6};$ ${1 2 3};$ ${2 3 4};$ ${3 4 5};$ ${4 5 6};$ ${1 2 3 4};$ ${2 3 4 5};$ ${3 4 5 6};$ ${1 2 3 4 5};$ ${2 3 4 5 6};$ ${1 2 3 4 5 6}.$

wrong answers:

${1};$ ${2};$ ${3};$ ${4};$ ${5};$ ${6}.$

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem, it would be helpful if you define what "segments of length k" means. Does this mean number of consecutive terms, array value, etc?

Comment: I  gave an example

Comment: Thank you! I see now.

Comment: Hint: Think about how many contingent sequences of length k there are in an array of length n, such that k < n and find a solid pattern.

Comment: I found answer  and my mistake, thanks

Comment: Ah my bad, just posted solution for refrence. If you caught your mistake then that's good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Finding a pattern is very useful.

**Solution**:

Say our array $n$ is $[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]$.

Assuming $k < n$, we can see that the number of $k$ contingent sequences in $n$ should be $[a_1, a_2, ..., a_k], [a_2, a_3, ..., a_{k+1}], ..., [a_{n - k + 1}, a_{n - k + 2}, ..., a_n]$.

In total, we can see there are $n - k + 1$ total sequences that satisfy, and we just need to add this up over all $j$ such that $k \leq j \leq n$.

This can be written as: $ \sum_{j = k}^{n} (n - j + 1) =  \boxed{\frac{(n - k + 1) * (n - k + 2)}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we can try to count the number of segment of lenght $i$ with $i\leq n$.
Given an array of lenght $n$, there are $n+1-i$: imagine a segment of lenght $i$ sliding on an array of lenght $n$ (the head of the segment could be placed in $n+1-i$ position because the first $i-1$ positions aren't valid).
Then we sum:
$$\sum_{i=k}^{n}n+1-i=\sum_{i=k}^{n}n+1-\sum_{i=k}^{n}i=(n+1-k)(n+1)-\dfrac{n*(n+1)}{2}+\dfrac{(k-1)*k}{2}=\dfrac{(n-k+1)(n-k+2)}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for answer